# How to remove a Binding in Flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, binding, flex4.5

I have this Code:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(trollImage, "width", vslider, "value");
BindingUtils.bindProperty(trollImage, "height", vslider, "value");
```

and the aproppriate Components are written in MXML:

```
<s:Image id="trollImage" source="http://clansql.comoj.com/meme/trollface-square.png"/>
<s:VSlider id="vslider" height="400" maximum="600" minimum="5" value="400"/>
```

I create the Bindings by pressing a button. And after I pressed another button, the binding should be removed.

I found a solution for Flex 3.5 [here](http://jvalentino.blogspot.com/2010/02/dear-john-how-do-i-remove-flex-bindings.html), but that doesn't work for Flex 4.5 because the Components don't have a `_bindings` property. How is that in Flex 4.5? Can someone tell me please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That Flex 3.5 solution looks very hackish to me anyway.

You should use [ChangeWatcher#unWatch()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/ChangeWatcher.html#unwatch%28%29). The `BindingUtils#bindProperty()` function returns an instance of ChangeWatcher.

In your case that would result in something like this:

```
var widthWatcher:ChangeWatcher = 
    BindingUtils.bindProperty(trollImage, "width", vslider, "value");
var heightWatcher:ChangeWatcher = 
    BindingUtils.bindProperty(trollImage, "height", vslider, "value");

widthWatcher.unWatch();
heightWatcher.unWatch();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exacly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindProperty%28%29) `BindingUtils.bindProperty()` returns [`ChangeWatcher` instance](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/ChangeWatcher.html) which you should use to destroy bindings. The pseudo code looks like the following:

```
private var trollImageWidthWatcher:ChangeWatcher;
private var trollImageHeightWatcher:ChangeWatcher;

private function firstButtonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trollImageWidthWatcher = BindingUtils.bindProperty(trollImage, "width", vslider, "value");
    trollImageHeightWatcher = BindingUtils.bindProperty(trollImage, "height", vslider, "value");
}

private function secondButtonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trollImageWidthWatcher.unwatch();
    trollImageHeightWatcher.unwatch();
}
```